# LZW compression & dictionary

Tags: c++, dictionary, compression, lzw

I'm looking into implementing LZW compression in C++, and not sure of the best dictionary implementation.

Hash table made sense, but I don't understand how I would be able to 'reassign' values. If the table gets full, I need to be able to start overwriting previous (oldest) multi-char dictionary entries. Hash table would require me to keep track of these, find it, remove it, and then insert the new one.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there anything that hinders you from using `std::map` or other standard map implementations?

Comment: Well, somebody just has to ask "what's wrong with libbzip2"? :-)

Comment: @ChristianStieber Maybe what's wrong with it is that it doesn't support the extremely fast LZW compression?

Comment: Would like some practice, not looking for things that make this too simple (STL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is actually **two** data structures put together:

1. A hash table.
2. A FIFO queue (to discard old table entries)).

You can implement them yourself if you're looking for practice as your comments suggest, or use the stl/sgi/c++11 implementations (unordered_map is the actual hash map, either through sgi or c++11, and a FIFO queue is a doubly linked list, such as std::deque).

The idea is that whenever you want to discard the oldest dictionary entry, you pop the last element in the queue, and then remove it from the hash table as well.

Answer (score 3):

The [Unix compress utility (source code link)](http://sourcecodebrowser.com/ncompress/4.2.4.2/compress42_8c_source.html) uses double hashing and periodic table clearing.

If you want fast compression and decompression, then there are *far* better choices than LZW, which is horribly obsolete.  You should look at fast, level 1 compression in [zlib](http://zlib.net/) (probably already on your machine), [LZO](http://www.oberhumer.com/opensource/lzo/), and [lz4](http://code.google.com/p/lz4/).

There is no reason to write new LZW code other than for instructional or entertainment value.  It is only of historical interest.  You could also study the compress utility for such instruction and entertainment.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I can't use links the same way, nor can I put paragraphs in a comment.

Comment: The reference to the compress source code and its strategy makes this a proper answer, along with a good advice. +1.

Comment: Wow, The Mark Adler? Cool.

Answer (score 2):

You must use two different structures in compression and decompression.

While compressing, you should use a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), since you must search the dictionary by content and not by key.

While decompressing, you access the dictionary in the more conventional way, that is, by key.
You could then use any associative array structures. like hashtables or even a vector/deque of strings (since your indexes are consecutive natural numbers).

Answer (score 0):

You can try 2 dictionaries implemented in [lzws](https://github.com/andrew-aladev/lzws):

1. Linked list, memory usage <= 327 KB.
2. Sparse array, memory usage <= 33.5 MB.